# When trying to Join a CSV to many feature classes within a gdb. Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to join a csv to all feature classes within a gdb based on FILENAME which is the unique identifier in both csv and feature classes. Then I want to field calculate over the fields i need.

I am getting the following error. `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.`

```
#Import modules
import arcpy, os, string, sys, csv, collections

#Set parameters
Working = address to gdb
Add_CSV = address to csv

arcpy.env.workspace = Working

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#Join CSV to feature classes in gdb and populate fields
csv_values = {
    row[3]: {"id": row[0], "Name": row[1], "Class": row[2]}
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Add_CSV, ["id", "Name", "Class", "FILENAME"])
}
for fc in fcList:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FILENAME", "AssetID", "AssetName", "AssetClass"]) as u_cursor:
        for filename, assetid, assetname, assetclass in u_cursor:
            csv_record = Add_CSV.get(filename)
            assert csv_record, "No value found for {} filename {} in CSV".format(fc, filename)
            id = csv_record["id"]
            name = csv_record["Name"]
            category = csv_record["Class"]
            u_cursor.updateRow([filename, id, name, class])
```

Comment: What is `Add_CSV = address to csv`? If that is a file path itself, what are you expecting from `Add_CSV.get(filename)`?

Comment: Its the path to the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
csv_record = Add_CSV.get(filename)
```

try:

```
csv_record = csv_values[filename]
```

You have already captured all the data from the CSV file (`Add_CSV`) and processed them into the dictionary `csv_values`, so matching them up to your feature class rows should be with that dictionary, not the file name.

(The error occurs because you're just working with the string file path, not with the CSV raw data!)

Comment: Thanks @Erica. I did initially use that however got the following error:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I worked around the error above. The next error is as follow:
AssertionError: No value found for _1XC07_CED_EE_EFB_ES04_CGG0_000038 filename 1XC07-CED-EE-EFB-ES04-CGG0-000038 in CSV

_1XC07_CED_EE_EFB_ES04_CGG0_000038 is the name of one of the feature classes in my geodatabase. Its seems as though it is trying to match the filename in CSV to the title of feature and not the "FILENAME" field within the feature class.

Comment: No, it's just giving you the custom error from `assert` that you asked for. It's attempting to find `1XC07-CED-EE-EFB-ES04-CGG0-000038` in the CSV, have you confirmed whether it's in there? Throwing in a `pprint(csv_values)` statement may help you debug.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. There are 10 feature classes in the gdb and only 2 records in the csv that match the first two feature classes. So it throws an error when it cant find the csv record for the third FC. and the script wont finish.

Comment: Use `if` conditionals to test whether the record is in the csv before you try to do anything with it. Or, `try`/`except` statements so it can continue processing even in the event of a failure. If you have further issues, you should really ask a new Question ... StackOverflow is designed to focus on one problem at a time, not be a general debugging and tutotrial site :)

Comment: (And definitely not trying to discourage you from asking for help! But a new question can get help from more than just me ;) )